# will_paginate 2.3.15 - creating unique id selector for each page link

Tags: ruby-on-rails, css-selectors, will-paginate

Using the will_paginate gem, I want to create output that looks like this for the `<a>` tags:

```
<div class="navPagination">
  <span class="disabled prev_page">Prev</span>
  <span class="current">1</span>
  <a id="pag-top-2" rel="next" href="/aba/2011/07/30?page=2">2</a>
  <a id="pag-top-Next" class="next_page" rel="next" href="/aba/2011/07/30?page=2">Next</a>
</div>
```

**Notice that both the `<a>` tags have a unique id selector.** How can I create unique selector id's for each will_paginate page?

Note: if this isn't enough info, let me know and I'll try to provide more context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here](http://thewebfellas.com/blog/2008/8/3/roll-your-own-pagination-links-with-will_paginate) is a very detailled article about customizing will_paginate's output writing your own renderer.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can fork will_paginate and change this line:

https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate/blob/v2.3.15/lib/will_paginate/view_helpers.rb#L307

for this code:

```
page_span page, text, :class => span_class, :id => "pag-top-#{text}"
```